# SQLiteDatabase, Updated Values not matching in select query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I got stuck in a very strange issue. Where i am able to update the db Values when when trying to fetching the rows corresponding to that values i am not getting anything.

[image]
In this database, i inserted these rows, the date were 29, june for the last two rows, but when i updated these dates to 15, and tried to fetch the rows corresponding to that date

```
    String where = COL_DATE + " = ?";
    String[] args = {"15"};
   Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_DAILY_EXPENSE, null, where, args, null, null, null);
```

Then    `Log.d(TAG, "Cursor count= " + cursor.getCount());`gives 0`

Where as by fetching through month, it gives count = 2.
So i concluded, that somewhere after updating the fields, its not matching that updated field for fetching that corresponding row. But why this is happening?? No Idea.

`

Comment: sent your **args** to single quots

Comment: Try using a raw query : db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM DAILY_EXPENSES WHERE DATE='" +date+"'" );

Comment: @MH thanks, but No effect

Answer (score 0):

The value in the database is a number.
The value you are searching for is a string, which is different.

The Android database API allows only strings as parameters in most places, so you have to insert the number directly into the SQL command:

```java
String where = COL_DATE + " = " + 15;
String[] args = null;
```